# Is there a single python module for colored text output in idle, Powershell and terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, terminal, colors, python-idle

I need a python module that prints a colored output text for input() and print() functions which works on idle, Powershell, and Linux consols.

I am just expecting few colors (no extra background features required) and the same functions should work equally on python idle, PowerShell, terminal, and cmd with full flexibility of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'clrprint' module which works for idle, terminal and PowerShell too

> pip install clrprint

```
from clrprint import *
clrhelp() # print's available colors and usage

user_input = clrinput("input please: ",clr='r') # just like input() [color is red]
clrprint('your text',user_input,clr='green') # just like print()
```

Take a look at https://github.com/AbhijithAJ/clrprint for more info and screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

clrprint does a good job of printing in color - 'b' for blue, 'g' for green, 'r' for red, 'd' for default (black), 'p' for purple & 'y' for yellow

To print a single value in color, use clr=color (specify the color in quotes)
To print multiple values in color, use clr=[list of color strings] (specify the colors in quotes, within a list.

**# pip install clrprint** as mentioned above

from clrprint import *

clrprint("Big data", clr='b')            **# Print 1 value on a line**

clrprint("Big", "data", clr=['y','d']) **# Print multiple values on the same line**

x = 5

clrprint("x =", x, clr=['g', 'p'])  **# Print variable value**

name = clrinput('Enter name: ', clr=['p', 'd'])  **# input a value**

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.